# HTTP Listener to receive file

Tags: c#, httplistener

I am trying to generate a HTTP Listener that will accept a file and save it to a location.

The code below sees that there is something comming in, however is not saving the file.

I would be grateful if you could review the code and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Listener();
    }
    public static void Listener()
    {
        const string prefix = "http://localhost:8082/";
        var listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException hlex)
        {
            return;
        }
        while (listener.IsListening)
        {
            var context = listener.GetContext();
            ProcessRequest(context);
        }
        listener.Close();
    }

    public static void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.RawUrl);
        var path = Path.Combine(@"c:\listenerFiles", filename);

        try
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
            Console.WriteLine(context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
            var receivingFile = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            Console.WriteLine(receivingFile);
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = receivingFile.Length;
            using (var s = context.Response.OutputStream)
            s.Write(receivingFile, 0, receivingFile.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return;
        }


    }

}
```

When this gets the file the error that it is throwing reads

UnauthorisedAccessExcetion

Access to the path 'c:\listenerFiles' is denied.

Comment: Why aren't you reporting any exceptions in your `try/catch`? You're probably getting an error which is then silently swallowed up.

Comment: I don't see any code that saves a file. I see code that reads a file and sends it to the caller

Comment: ive just added the error im getting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do i need to do to save the file here please as the filename is currently blank when i debug and step into it

Comment: @SimonPrice have you tried to write something on your own? Asking the Internet to convert code for you is frowned upon. At the very least try to read the request stream and use File.WriteXXX to write it

Comment: and if you look I am using the stream to write with s.Write

Comment: @SimonPrice: You are writing a file out to the client, not to your server's disk.

Comment: You are writing to the output stream, not to a file. This code reads a file from disk and sends it to the client, while you asked for code that does the opposite: reads a file sent from the client and writes it to disk. What I've asked is: have you tried to write code that reads the request stream and writes the contents to a disk file?

Answer (score 3):

Never ever ever catch an exception without handling it! `catch (Exception e){ return; }` is just forbidden!

It is a bad idea to use `using` on the `OutputStream`, since it is disposed after the `using`, so the HTTP handler can't pick it up afterwards. Remove the `using` and see if it works.

Also check if the IIS process has access to the path the file resides.

Comment: Note the OP asked about *storing* a file, yet the code *reads* a file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I guess he did mean "receiving on the client". Then the code is exactly what he asks.

Comment: thats not a standard style of mine, im just using it at the moment to catch it at a breakpoint to see the error easy enough

Comment: @PatrickHofman the latest comment suggests the OP does want to save but the code isn't his own. The code still shouldn't be swallowing exceptions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any reason why you are so rude? do you code everything yourself or when you dont know how to do something do you use an example and modify it to your own needs?  This is meant to be a site where people help each other when we are stuck.. not to point and make fun!

Comment: @PatrickHofman im currently unable to read the receiving file. are you able to help please.

Comment: I'm not being rude. I'm pointing out that you need to try to solve the problem first. Copying someone else's code and asking SO to fix it *is* considered against SO guidelines and not the polite way to ask. Notice I haven't downvoted the question yet. I've also pointed to so many hints in comments that you can write the code yourself. Just check the documentation of the **Request** object, and try to find the **Stream** in it. Then use one of the **File.WriteXXX** methods to write the contents to disk

Comment: I agree with Panagiotis. You need to get your question straight first. My answer is based on the information you provided and proves to be not what you want. Come with an updated version of your question + attempt and I will update my answer.